# Android Studio org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException:

Tags: android, gradle

**I want to integrate the country code picker by hbb20. I put the dependency and build, it's fine but whenever I try to run the app then I got this error:**

`Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.`

**My build.gradle app level codes:**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.teamphoenix.amarflat"
        minSdk 22
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation "com.github.skydoves:powerspinner:1.1.9"
    implementation 'com.hbb20:ccp:2.4.7'
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I have had the same problem using mik3y's usb-to-serial.

I wrongly used:

> com.github.mik3y:usb-serial-for-android:Tag

and changing it to :

> com.github.mik3y:usb-serial-for-android:3.4.3

solved the problem.

I recommend you review all your dependencies, probably one of them does not point correctly to its repository, I hope I can help you.
By the way, surely the ***(```)*** at the end of the code was just an editing error, right?

Comment: One of the dependencies for the country code picker was missing, I added it manually, and it worked!

Comment: It works for me, I have a dependency  "com.google.firebase:firebase-iid" causing problems. I change to "com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:17.0.2", and it solves the problem

Comment: I have same issue but none of these answers, solved my issue!

Answer (score 4):

I have same issue.
My issue solved when

> **

- Gradle Toggle offline mode off

**

.
Just click Toggle offline mode and set mode off.